# Python CSV Reader: No Get Line Function?

Tags: python, csv, iterator, generator

I have been reading the Python docs on the CSV module here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

And I noticed that it does not mention any way for a reader object to return the number of the line it is currently reading, or which iteration it is currently at. This seems like it would be a widely needed functionality. So, I am wondering how one can do this:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(readFile)
    for row in reader:
        # do something 
        # now want to find the line number that row corresponds to
```

Or if that is not possible, why that is the case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reader object is an iterator, so you can always use `enumerate` to get the line number:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(readFile)
for line_number, row in enumerate(reader):
     # some code
```

`enumerate` also lets you specify a custom starting index:

```
for line_number, row in enumerate(reader, 2):
    # line number starts at 2
```

`enumerate` isn't only limited to the `reader` object of the `csv` module but works in general with iterables and iterators.